# Manga where the protagonist boards a plane and is warned by a friend with a lucky charm

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga starts with the protagonist boarding a plane (or already in the plane) when they show that he is warned by a friend who is, as stated by him, always right because of his intuition and gave the protagonist a lucky charm.

The day the main character will board the plane he suddenly remembered his friend's advice to him and bought an oxygen mask and a parachute with him. After the plane takes off an explosion happens and he immediately puts on his gas mask and uses his parachute. When he lands he notices that he is in a forest and takes off his mask but suddenly he has a hard time breathing and puts on the mask again.

The other details I remember are him running out of oxygen and falling in a lake or pond where he came in contact with something that allows him to breath in that world and he also found out that his friend also came to the world but earlier than him and now he is dead.

This might be a novel and I mistakenly thought of it as manga because sometimes I visualize the events happening when I read novels.

I think I read it in between 2019-2020 but since I read it on kissmanga I don't remember the exact date because you know, kisscommunity, in general, shut down which included kissmanga so I can't check. They did provide a way to recover the titles bookmarked but I mostly read on my phone. If details is needed then I remember the mc, after drowning and getting the ability to breath in that world, arrive in a ruined village where he found a girl with some kind of disease and he also found a dungeon beneath the village when he lift up a trapdoor of one of the house.

The probability of this being a novel is increasing.

Comment: This might be a novel and I mistakenly thought of it as manga because sometimes I visualize the events happening when I read novels.

Comment: Hi again, could you recall any more details such as when you read this? I'd highly recommend looking at this [post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) that will help you see what details we find useful to include to help us help you :D If you haven't already, you might find it useful to read what's in the [help] and take the [tour].

Comment: I think I read it in between 2019-2020 but since I read it on kissmanga I don't remember the exact date because you know, kisscommunity, in general, shut down which included kissmanga so I can't check. They did provide a way to recover the titles bookmarked but I mostly read on my phone. If details is needed then I remember the mc, after drowning and getting the ability to breath in that world, arrive in a ruined village where he found a girl with some kind of disease and he also found a dungeon beneath the village when he lift up a trapdoor of one of the house.

Comment: The probability of this being a novel is increasing.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include this information please? You don't need to signal the edit, but just work it into the text.